# Como pasar un parámetro a un join en una consulta Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-sql

Tengo la siguiente consulta Linq:

```
var proveedores = (from x in context.ProveedorMateriales
                   join pc in context.ProveedoresCompañiasLinked on
                        x.ProveedorId equals pc.ProveedorId
                   join p in context.Proveedores on 
                        pc.ProveedorId equals p.ProveedorId
                   join pre in context.Precios on 
                        x.ProveedorMaterialId equals pre.ProveedorMaterialId
                   where pc.CompañiaId == compañiaId &&
                         mat.Contains(x.MaterialId.ToString()) &&
                         pre.Status == Status.Activo
                   select x).ToList();
```

**La información se recupera bien a excepción de los precios**, que dentro de los ProveedoresMateriales **puedo ver mas de un Precio**, cuando lo que **requiero** es que solo me cargue **el Precio cuyo Status sea igual a Status.Activo**.

En el join necesito algo como esto:

```
join pre in context.Precios on 
    x.ProveedorMaterialId equals pre.ProveedorMaterialId && 
    pre.Status equals Status.Activo
```

Pero el uso del operador "&&" no es valido en el contexto del join...

¿Alguna sugerencia para realizar este filtro?

Comment: Según mencionas, estás utilizando Entity Framework 6. Definiste propiedades de navegación para cada una de las clases POCO? Esto te evita la necesidad de la instrucción Join y así simplificar sustancialmente la consulta Linq. Si pudieses brindar más detalles de la definición de las clases POCO sería de gran ayuda para brindarte una solución adecuada.

Comment: No será que un ProveedorMateriales tiene mas de un precio en Status Activo????

Comment: @jose luis garcia Esta respuesta es solo una pregunta para saber porque despues de analizar la consulta que haces lo unico extraño que veo es el join con la Tabla Proveedores si al final no estas haciendo ninguna pregunta sobre sus campos o la estas seleccionando al final...

Comment: ¿qué es `mat` en este contexto?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto:

```
var query = from t1 in myTABLE1List
            join t2 in myTABLE1List on 
                 new { t1.ColumnA, t1.ColumnB } equals 
                 new { t2.ColumnA, t2.ColumnB }
```

Comment: Hola: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero lamentablemente no me sirve, esa fue una de las primeras cosas que intente pero si te das cuenta en mi pregunta **yo necesito pasarle un parámetro al join el cual es el valor del enum _Status_**, lo que me sugieres no me funciona debido a que ambos parámetros deben de estar en ambas tablas y este no es mi caso... Gracias por tu respuesta e interés.

Answer (score 0):

El filtro de estatus deberias definirlo en el join

```
var proveedores = (from x in context.ProveedorMateriales
                    join pc in context.ProveedoresCompañiasLinked on x.ProveedorId equals pc.ProveedorId
                    join p in context.Proveedores on pc.ProveedorId equals p.ProveedorId
                    join pre in context.Precios.Where(x=> x.Status == "activo") on x.ProveedorMaterialId equals pre.ProveedorMaterialId
                   where pc.CompañiaId == compañiaId 
                        && mat.Contains(x.MaterialId.ToString()) 
                   select x).ToList();
```

como veras filtras los precios activos usando

```
join pre in context.Precios.Where(x=> x.Status == "activo")
```

Lo que no me queda claro es de donde sale `mat` y porque te deja filtrar por `pc.CompañiaId` cuando claramente seria el mismo problema que el precio

Nota: definir el where de esa forma para que quede claro el filtro ya que no se que tipo de dato es el campo `status`, si es bool puede cambiarlo